# Using another alternative than Google maps Provider in Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, leaflet, maps, maplibre-gl

Hello dear community,

I'm actually working on a mobile app using react-native expo, I used to work on react-native but I switched to expo, and as you know mapbox is not compatible in expo since it requires native modules, I searched a lot of examples and modules to try to develop a map instead of the default one because Google maps requires billing, is there a way to work with maplibre or another map provider? I checked some and most of them are outdated.

I did some research on some modules and projects that were developed using another alternaive providers but none of them works and most these modules are were outdated.